# ¿Como recibir un valor aleatorio de un rango de enteros espedificados?

Tags: sql, sql-server, random

Cómo podría "si se puede" insertar en un campo de cada uno de los registros de una tabla, un valor comprendido en un rango de valores especificado.
Por ejemplo, tengo una tabla con 500 registros, estos contienen un campo de tipo entero que está en null, yo quiero setear en cada uno de estos campos un valor aleatorio que esté en (1,54,32,9,5,6).

¿Puedo hacerlo?
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que

- Generalmente se puede obtener un número aleatorio dentro de un rango de números (que inician y terminan en números conocidos, sin agujeros)
- Los números entre los que quieres elegir el resultado no son un rango de este tipo

Puedes valerte de una variable tipo tabla, para poder asociar cada número de tu conjunto de datos con un número de un rango de números y luego seleccionar entre estos el resultado final.

Esto puedes hacerlo con algo como:

```
declare @Numeros as table (id int not null identity primary key, Numero int not null unique);

insert into @Numeros (numero) values (1), (54), (32), (9), (5), (6);
```

Lo que nos dará como resultado un `id` que va consecutivamente de 1 a N, asociado a cada número del conjunto deseado.

He preparado un ejemplo con una tabla temporal, con una columna llamada `NumeroAleatorio`, a la que inserto primero 500 registros dejando `NumeroAleatorio` en `null`.  Luego hago un `update` para poner un número aleatorio dentro del conjunto `(1, 54, 32, 9, 5, 6)` en dicha columna:

```
declare @Numeros as table (id int not null identity primary key, Numero int not null unique);

insert into @Numeros (numero) values (1), (54), (32), (9), (5), (6);

create table #Ejemplo (
    id int not null identity primary key
  , NumeroGenerado int
  , NumeroAleatorio int
);

with
  RE (N) as (select 1 union all select N from RE)
, E1 as (select top 10 * from RE) --10
, E2 as (select a.N from E1 a, E1 b) --100
, E4 as (select a.N from E2 a, E2 b) --10000
, Enteros as (select top 500 row_number() over (order by (select null)) N from E4)
insert into #Ejemplo (NumeroGenerado)
select N from Enteros;

with
Aleatorio as (
select id, ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(6)) % (select count(1) from @Numeros)) + 1 idAleatorio
  from #Ejemplo
)
update #Ejemplo
   set NumeroAleatorio = na.Numero
  from #Ejemplo
       inner join Aleatorio on Aleatorio.id = #Ejemplo.id
       inner join @Numeros na on na.id = Aleatorio.idAleatorio;
```

Para hacer el `update`, primero preparo un CTE donde asocio cada ID en la tabla `#Ejemplo` con un `id` aleatorio de la tabla `@Numeros`. Finalmente, hago join entre la tabla `#Ejemplo`, mi tabla al vuelo `Aleatorio` y la tabla `@Numeros` que contiene el conjunto del que se puede seleccionar.

Esto, en cada corrida me devuelve resultados diferentes, este es el resultado de una corrida de prueba:

```
(6 rows affected)

(500 rows affected)

(500 rows affected)
id          NumeroGenerado NumeroAleatorio
----------- -------------- ---------------
1           1              9
2           2              5
3           3              6
4           4              54
5           5              9
6           6              54
7           7              32
8           8              32
9           9              5
10          10             6
11          11             5
12          12             5
13          13             9
14          14             1
15          15             6
16          16             1
17          17             9
18          18             6
19          19             54
20          20             5
21          21             9
22          22             9
23          23             5
24          24             1
25          25             9
26          26             6
27          27             9
28          28             9
29          29             32
30          30             6
31          31             54
32          32             5
33          33             6
34          34             54
35          35             6
36          36             32
37          37             6
38          38             6
39          39             1
40          40             1
41          41             1
42          42             6
43          43             6
44          44             1
45          45             32
46          46             54
47          47             32
48          48             32
49          49             9
50          50             1
51          51             32
52          52             54
53          53             54
54          54             32
55          55             1
56          56             1
57          57             1
58          58             54
59          59             5
60          60             54
61          61             32
62          62             6
63          63             9
64          64             6
65          65             9
66          66             1
67          67             32
68          68             6
69          69             32
70          70             6
71          71             6
72          72             54
73          73             6
74          74             9
75          75             5
76          76             32
77          77             5
78          78             5
79          79             9
80          80             6
81          81             54
82          82             9
83          83             1
84          84             6
85          85             32
86          86             1
87          87             32
88          88             54
89          89             32
90          90             6
91          91             6
92          92             5
93          93             9
94          94             6
95          95             1
96          96             5
97          97             1
98          98             5
99          99             6
100         100            6
101         101            6
102         102            54
103         103            6
104         104            5
105         105            1
106         106            6
107         107            32
108         108            9
109         109            9
110         110            54
111         111            1
112         112            6
113         113            9
114         114            1
115         115            1
116         116            32
117         117            32
118         118            5
119         119            6
120         120            9
121         121            9
122         122            54
123         123            32
124         124            32
125         125            6
126         126            32
127         127            5
128         128            1
129         129            32
130         130            1
131         131            9
132         132            1
133         133            5
134         134            9
135         135            6
136         136            9
137         137            32
138         138            1
139         139            1
140         140            32
141         141            5
142         142            6
143         143            32
144         144            32
145         145            5
146         146            6
147         147            54
148         148            9
149         149            5
150         150            5
151         151            54
152         152            54
153         153            54
154         154            1
155         155            54
156         156            6
157         157            6
158         158            9
159         159            5
160         160            54
161         161            1
162         162            9
163         163            9
164         164            5
165         165            6
166         166            6
167         167            32
168         168            1
169         169            32
170         170            1
171         171            54
172         172            1
173         173            6
174         174            6
175         175            1
176         176            54
177         177            9
178         178            1
179         179            32
180         180            1
181         181            6
182         182            9
183         183            9
184         184            6
185         185            6
186         186            1
187         187            1
188         188            5
189         189            1
190         190            54
191         191            5
192         192            32
193         193            9
194         194            1
195         195            1
196         196            5
197         197            32
198         198            6
199         199            5
200         200            32
201         201            54
202         202            32
203         203            5
204         204            32
205         205            54
206         206            32
207         207            9
208         208            1
209         209            54
210         210            1
211         211            32
212         212            5
213         213            54
214         214            5
215         215            32
216         216            32
217         217            5
218         218            6
219         219            32
220         220            54
221         221            1
222         222            6
223         223            5
224         224            5
225         225            32
226         226            32
227         227            9
228         228            54
229         229            32
230         230            5
231         231            1
232         232            54
233         233            1
234         234            54
235         235            6
236         236            6
237         237            32
238         238            6
239         239            9
240         240            1
241         241            9
242         242            6
243         243            6
244         244            32
245         245            6
246         246            1
247         247            32
248         248            54
249         249            9
250         250            32
251         251            6
252         252            54
253         253            32
254         254            54
255         255            54
256         256            54
257         257            9
258         258            6
259         259            9
260         260            9
261         261            5
262         262            32
263         263            5
264         264            32
265         265            9
266         266            6
267         267            1
268         268            1
269         269            6
270         270            32
271         271            6
272         272            54
273         273            6
274         274            54
275         275            5
276         276            32
277         277            54
278         278            5
279         279            5
280         280            54
281         281            6
282         282            1
283         283            9
284         284            5
285         285            1
286         286            32
287         287            32
288         288            32
289         289            32
290         290            9
291         291            9
292         292            9
293         293            1
294         294            9
295         295            9
296         296            5
297         297            32
298         298            9
299         299            32
300         300            54
301         301            1
302         302            1
303         303            32
304         304            5
305         305            6
306         306            9
307         307            6
308         308            32
309         309            6
310         310            6
311         311            54
312         312            1
313         313            54
314         314            54
315         315            1
316         316            32
317         317            5
318         318            1
319         319            9
320         320            6
321         321            32
322         322            9
323         323            32
324         324            5
325         325            32
326         326            5
327         327            1
328         328            6
329         329            1
330         330            1
331         331            32
332         332            5
333         333            32
334         334            9
335         335            1
336         336            5
337         337            32
338         338            1
339         339            9
340         340            5
341         341            32
342         342            9
343         343            6
344         344            1
345         345            5
346         346            1
347         347            54
348         348            54
349         349            54
350         350            54
351         351            9
352         352            32
353         353            9
354         354            32
355         355            5
356         356            5
357         357            9
358         358            5
359         359            32
360         360            6
361         361            9
362         362            6
363         363            1
364         364            5
365         365            32
366         366            32
367         367            6
368         368            32
369         369            1
370         370            54
371         371            1
372         372            1
373         373            9
374         374            5
375         375            32
376         376            32
377         377            5
378         378            5
379         379            6
380         380            1
381         381            5
382         382            54
383         383            9
384         384            5
385         385            9
386         386            6
387         387            5
388         388            5
389         389            54
390         390            6
391         391            54
392         392            9
393         393            6
394         394            5
395         395            9
396         396            9
397         397            9
398         398            1
399         399            9
400         400            6
401         401            32
402         402            32
403         403            9
404         404            1
405         405            32
406         406            1
407         407            5
408         408            6
409         409            54
410         410            54
411         411            1
412         412            1
413         413            54
414         414            1
415         415            5
416         416            5
417         417            6
418         418            54
419         419            1
420         420            5
421         421            5
422         422            32
423         423            54
424         424            9
425         425            1
426         426            54
427         427            5
428         428            9
429         429            32
430         430            54
431         431            9
432         432            32
433         433            9
434         434            5
435         435            6
436         436            1
437         437            9
438         438            1
439         439            6
440         440            32
441         441            5
442         442            5
443         443            54
444         444            32
445         445            1
446         446            1
447         447            54
448         448            32
449         449            5
450         450            9
451         451            5
452         452            9
453         453            9
454         454            9
455         455            5
456         456            5
457         457            32
458         458            6
459         459            32
460         460            5
461         461            6
462         462            6
463         463            6
464         464            6
465         465            9
466         466            6
467         467            1
468         468            54
469         469            32
470         470            5
471         471            54
472         472            9
473         473            32
474         474            1
475         475            54
476         476            32
477         477            54
478         478            1
479         479            54
480         480            9
481         481            32
482         482            6
483         483            6
484         484            9
485         485            32
486         486            6
487         487            54
488         488            32
489         489            1
490         490            1
491         491            5
492         492            9
493         493            5
494         494            32
495         495            54
496         496            9
497         497            5
498         498            5
499         499            1
500         500            32

(500 rows affected)


Completion time: 2020-09-14T00:52:41.2146317-06:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Existen varias formas de generar números aleatorios en SQL. Con el escenario que describes, vamos a probar una manera de realizarlo:

```
Create table dbo.ej
             (
             id     int
           , number int
             );
go
```

Ya disponemos de una tabla, que vamos a llenar con 500 filas.

```
with c1 as (
    Select 1 as n from (values(1),(1),(1))T(n)),
    c2 as (
    Select c1.n from c1 cross join c1 as b),
    c3 as (
    Select c2.n from c2 cross join c2 as b),
    c4 as (
    Select c3.n from c3 cross join c3 as b),
    c5 as (
    select top(500) ROW_NUMBER () over (order by n) as row 
    from c4
    )
    Insert into dbo.ej(id, number)
    Select c5.row, null
    from c5;
```

Ahora con 500 filas sin datos para la columna number, vamos a pensar en como definir el aleatorio y su rango.

```
Update e 
    Set number = 
        (ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(6)) %100) + 1)
From dbo.ej e
```

Como puedes observar de la sentencia, el rango definido está entre 1 y 100.

[image: Resultado]

Para cambiar de rango, tan simple como modificar el valor 100 por otro.

Te dejo un enlace sobre otras 5 maneras de generar aleatorios.

[Sql Authority. Sql Random](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/29/sql-server-random-number-generator-script-sql-query/)